# Setting up Raspberry Pi 4B to be a wifi access point

Tags: wifi, pi-4, access-point

I want my Raspberry Pi 4B to create a wireless network that connects to my router, without using any external devices to assist the pi (ie. a secondary router or an antennae that would connect to the pi).

The 4B would connect to a wifi network wirelessly, then I would connect the Pi network. Most tutorials are about the 3 and do not work when I try them. Note that I am a pi beginner, and this is my first project.

Comment: You seem to be unclear whether you want an Access Point (**WHY?**) or connect to a router or what you expect to do with the resultant. See [How to set up networking/WiFi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) to setup networking - there are dozens of Access Point tutorials, so it seems futile to point to one which you claim doesn't work.

Comment: "*I do not want to use a secondary router; just using the wireless capabilities of the 4B.*" By this section, you mean that you don't have any wireless devices and you want to create an AP for your wireless clients. || Although by this part, "*The 4B would connect to a wifi network wirelessly, then I would connect the Pi network.*", I realized that you want to make Raspberry Pi as a wireless bridge device. || Please make it clear.

Comment: As already stated, the question is unclear.  Title suggests that you want the RPi to provide a Wireless Access Point.  Question says that you want the RPi to connect to a Wifi Access point.  Please clarify.

Comment: Edit: I clarified the question

Comment: I think you search for `SoftAp mode`. You have two interfaces on wlan0, one in managed (client) type `managed` and one in master (AP) type `__ap`. Connect your managed interface to your router. Use master interface for `hostpad` and your own Wi-Fi Access Point. (Not tested on RPi4)

Comment: HUGE UPDATE: Open Vwr DOES support the pi 4 officially, but from my knowledge, it will only support it in Chinese. I highly recomend watching this video on how to set it up. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6bAZ0QZC90). Please correct me if i am wrong, because currently, translating is tedious. Thanks to @M. Rostami for telling me to use Open Vwr in the first place. You are very appreciated.

Comment: @BigBird My pleasure. I've updated the answer. It's not Chinese.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenWrt is the best choice for you. It makes Raspberry Pi to a wireless router device and you don't need to run a lot of commands. Easy to use with an interactive web user interface named LuCi like picture below:

[image]

I believe it going to help you better than in other ways.
The thing you should concern is that you should don't attend [this page](https://openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi_foundation/raspberry_pi). As this page, OpenWrt is not on the supported list, however, you can install the `bcm2709` by [this link - Index of (root) / snapshots / targets / brcm2708 / bcm2709](https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/targets/brcm2708/bcm2709/). Download `rpi-2-ext4-factory.img.gz` and write the image on a larger 256MB SD-Card.

The default IP is `192.168.1.1` and the DHCP server is disabled therefore add and static IP address to the host you want to configure RPi (such as `192.168.1.100`), the default user is `root` and leave the password section blank.
Go to `Network/Wireless` then turn `radio0` or WLAN on.

As I mentioned, it's easy to configure OpenWrt and you can configure it any way you want.

---

**UPDATE:**
Raspberry Pi 4 sources provided by the Raspberry Pi Foundation are Linux >= 4.19.
OpenWrt 18.06 is based on Linux 4.9 and OpenWrt 19.07 is based on Linux 4.14, so you need to use the snapshots builds, which are based on Linux 4.19:
https://downloads.openwrt.org/snapshots/targets/brcm2708/bcm2711/

Download `rpi-4-ext4-factory.img.gz` and write the image to the SD-Card.

---

**UPDATE 02**:
Snapshot builds do not include the web interface, the LuCi package. Therefore, follow the procedure:

**1.** Connect to the Raspberry Pi's terminal via `SSH`.
**2.** Update package list of OpenWrt:

```
opkg update
```

**3.** Install LuCi package which is the web interface configuration mode:

```
opkg install luci
```

Comment: Just making sure im doing this right. 1. installing only rpi-2-ext4-factory.img.gz on my computer. 2. putting it on my pi sd card? 3. add my static ip to OpenWrt. 4. Turn radio0 or WLAN on. 3. I want to start it on startup, so i would use autostart to configure it to start automatically.
How do i know if i want to turn on radi0 or WLAN? And do you mean the router ip of the pi is 192.168.1.1?

Comment: *1-2.* Yes, Write `rpi-2-ext4-factory.img.gz` on an SD-Card and put it to your Raspberry Pi 4. || *3.* No, change your computer IP address to something like `192.168.1.x`. (the `x` can be a number between `2` to `254` like `192.168.1.25). || *4.* Yes. || "*I want to start it on startup, so I would use autostart to configure it to start automatically.*" You don't need to change any configuration. It has configured itself.

Comment: || "*How do i know if i want to turn on radi0 or WLAN?*" I don't get what you mean. || "*do you mean the router ip of the pi is 192.168.1.1?*", No, After you put the SD-Card to the Raspberry Pi and turn it on, the Raspberry Pi would be up with `192.168.1.1` IP address, therefore, after you change the computer IP address, you can put `192.168.1.1` on the computer's web browser to open LuCi web interface which is the Raspberry Pi (OpenWrt) configuration environment.

Comment: "Go to Network/Wireless then turn radio0 or WLAN on." I wanted to know how i would know which one to turn on. So, Technically i could not use a vpn on my computer because it would change the IP adress (I know how to change my IP adress but I just wanted to confirm i could not use my vpn while connected to my pi.)

Comment: Oh and which folder to i put rpi-2-ext4-factory.img.gz in?

Comment: Extract the "rpi-2-ext4-factory.img.gz" and by that, you'll have a "rpi-2-ext4-factory.img". So, add this file to Win32DiskImager and hit the write button. Wait till the finished message appear. Finally, put the SD-Card to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: The radio0/WLAN is in a particular section. There is one of them on the configuration interface. Never mind, it's not essential.

Comment: So i started up OpenWrt and typed in `uci set network.lan.ipaddr : 192.168.1.2`,`uci commit`, and `reboot -f` to make the ip address more identifiable. However, when i typed in http://192.168.1.2, it says that it refused to connect. I tried this on Chrome and on Opera. Any help?

Comment: What was your computer IP address? Did you set that `192.168.2.1`?

Comment: i tried the updated version but luci wouldnt open.

Comment: @BigBird As I said, its snapshot builds. Therefore, you need to connect to the RPi by `SSH` and install the LuCi. **1.** `opkg update` - **2.** `opkg install luci`.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you want to have an access point that is connected with a WiFi client connection as uplink to your internet. All tutorials and automated scripts I know that work with the RasPi are made to use a wired uplink to the internet router router but not a wireless one. This is because it isn't an easy task to have a wireless access point and a wireless client uplink with only the on-board WiFi device. But it is possible if you respect a strict order by managing the network interfaces. How to do it you can look at [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/89804/79866). You only need to install **hostapd** as helper. All other things are built-in and you only have to configure it.