# How to use Raspberry PI4 as a security device for the network?

Tags: raspbian, python, security

**How Can I use Raspberry Pi 4 as a antivirus or a security device in a Network?**

I am trying to make the raspberry pi become a security device example below.

---(Internet)----(PI 4)-----(Local-PC)

That PI 4 needs to be a security for the internet.

Comment: Search Google for "PiHole".

Comment: @Dougie As far as I know "PiHole" is for outbound traffic, manly to block DNS traffic so obscure programs cannot call home.

Comment: Is your PC really connected straight to the internet? It's possible, but unusual. People usually have a router between the Internet and the PC, which will give some security. Your question is a bit backwards - you don't state what security you're trying to gain - but it's likely the router will do much the same as the Pi.

Answer (score 1):

OpenWrt is a OS/tools that you can write on the SD-Card and run on your raspberry pi. In [this link](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/107006/44221), you can find the image file and some explanation.

It's easy to configure the OpenWrt. All you need is configure the `eth0` or `br0` (by default) as the WAN port and connect your modem port (internet) then share it by `wlan0`.

It can be your simple firewall that is easy to use. More information is [here](https://computers.tutsplus.com/articles/installing-openwrt-on-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-new-home-firewall--mac-55984).

---

On the other hand, you can configure you Raspbian/Archlinux/etc as a network firewall that is a bit complicated. Check [this link](https://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Firewall-and-Intrusion-Detection-Syst/) out to get some information about configuration.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know there was OpenWRT for RasPi (although, I should've guessed, it was only a matter of time...)